# Can't figure out why counter doesn't work with tags

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my first question and I am quite a noob when it comes to coding
I am currently working on an app, with a quiz, that is sort of a personality type of quiz,
so, most of your answers are A, that means you are a "Engineering"-type of person, most answers are B, you are a "Computer-Science" person...
Anyway, i have a form with a label and 4 buttons with  1 to 4 Tags each, the label shows the question, the buttons the answers, but i cannot find the error, why my counter doesnt work and results are always shown as 0s.. Anybody got an idea?

```
  public partial class StudienTESTT : Form
    {

        public int frageNummer = 1;
        public int scoreLS;
        public int scoreCS;
        public int scoreEE;
        public int scoreIE;

        public int totalFragen;
        public StudienTESTT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Fragen(frageNummer);

            totalFragen = 10;
        }

        private void checkAntwortEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            var senderObject = (Button)sender;

            int buttonTag = Convert.ToInt32(senderObject.Tag);

            if (buttonTag == 1)
            {
                scoreLS++;
            }
            else if (buttonTag == 2)
            {
                scoreCS++;
            }
            else if (buttonTag == 3)
            {
                scoreEE++;
            }
            else if (buttonTag == 4)
            {
                scoreIE++;
            }

            if (frageNummer == totalFragen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Hier ist deine Persönliche Test auswertung" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Du hast " + scoreLS + " Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Life Science Engineering beantwortet." + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Du hast " + scoreCS + " Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Computer Sciences beantwortet." + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Du hast " + scoreEE + " Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Electronic Engineering beantwortet." + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Du hast " + scoreIE + " Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Industrial Engineering beantwortet." + Environment.NewLine +

                    "Klicke auf OK, wenn du es nochmal versuchen magst");

                scoreLS = 0;
                scoreCS = 0;
                scoreEE = 0;
                scoreIE = 0;

                frageNummer = 0;
                Fragen(frageNummer);
            }
            frageNummer++;
            Fragen(frageNummer);
        }

        private void Fragen(int num)
        {
            switch (num)
            {

                case 1:
                    labFrage.Text = "Welches Schulfach ist dir am Liebsten? ";

                    button5.Text = "Naturwissenschaften! ALLE Naturwissenschaften!";
                    button6.Text = "Informatik";
                    button7.Text = "Hauptsächlich Mathematik";
                    button8.Text = "Physik oder Mathe... oder beides";


                    break;
```

first q. as an example, and i hope its not a problem its partially in german

Comment: that's a great moment to learn about your IDEs debugger, break your program after reading in `buttonTag` and checking what value it has. because otherwise, your code seems solid - so my guess is that converting that tag doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Did you give the button's Tag a value?

Answer (score 0):

July,

Your code (including the counter) worked just fine for me. The only thing I can think of is that either, you forgot to assign `checkAntwortEvent` to the click event handlers of each of your four buttons, or you forgot to add the numbers into the tag properties of each button. Below is a working (refactored) implementation of your code that adds the event handlers and tag properties at runtime:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Fragen(frageNummer);
    totalFragen = 10;
    button5.Click += checkAntwortEvent;button6.Click += checkAntwortEvent;
    button7.Click += checkAntwortEvent;button8.Click += checkAntwortEvent;
    button5.Tag = 1;button6.Tag = 2;button7.Tag = 3;button8.Tag = 4;
}
public int frageNummer = 1, scoreLS, scoreCS, scoreEE, scoreIE, totalFragen;
private void checkAntwortEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderObject = (Button)sender;
    var buttonTag = Convert.ToInt32(senderObject.Tag);
    switch (buttonTag)
    {
        case 1: scoreLS++; break;case 2: scoreCS++; break;
        case 3: scoreEE++; break;case 4: scoreIE++; break;
    }
    if (frageNummer == totalFragen)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($@"Hier ist deine Persönliche Test auswertung
Du hast {scoreLS} Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Life Science Engineering beantwortet.
Du hast {scoreCS} Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Computer Sciences beantwortet.
Du hast {scoreEE} Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Electronic Engineering beantwortet.
Du hast {scoreIE} Fragen mit Antworten der Kategorie Industrial Engineering beantwortet.
Klicke auf OK, wenn du es nochmal versuchen magst");
        scoreLS = scoreCS = scoreEE = scoreIE = frageNummer = 0;
        Fragen(frageNummer);
    }
    Fragen(++frageNummer);
}
private void Fragen(int num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            labFrage.Text = "Welches Schulfach ist dir am Liebsten? ";
            button5.Text = "Naturwissenschaften! ALLE Naturwissenschaften!";
            button6.Text = "Informatik";
            button7.Text = "Hauptsächlich Mathematik";
            button8.Text = "Physik oder Mathe... oder beides";
            break;
    }
}
}
```